# Anchor tag inside button not clickable on Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several buttons like this one, each one of them created dinamically. Note the number in the id "myDropdown + #" will be the same as its parent container, in this case the button.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button id="1" type="button" class="dropbtn" onclick="sendId(this.id)">Hello
    <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content show">
       <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
       <a href="https://www.fb.com">Facebook</a>
       <a href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
    </div>
</button>
</div>
```

and this is my Javascript

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function sendId(ide) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("myDropdown" + ide).classList.toggle("show");
    }

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
$(window).click(function (e) {
        //alert(e.target.nodeName);
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('dropbtn')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I took this dropdown from http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp and modified it to have several of them. 
The issue is, the dropdown shows just how it should and the anchor tag clicks work just fine on any browser, but not on IE (Edge to be specific). I used `alert(e.target.nodeName);` to know which element triggered the event and when I click on an anchor tag, the alert shows the BUTTON element (its parent container) as if it was the button element the one being clicked. What is causing the anchor tags to not getting clicked and how do I make them clickable?

Comment: You need to use some standards

Comment: Please try use $(document).click instead of $(window).click

Comment: Also please put <div id="myDropdown1" outside of the button the element.

Comment: run that html through w3c validator...be careful how you arbitrarily construct your html .. tags have specific allowed content